# Unable to access certificate store

Tags: ssl

I have a xmpp server (openfire 3.9.3) and trying to secure my non-ssl connection to ssl connection.

that's why i have created a self-signed certificate using java keytool as

```
keytool -genkey -keystore keystore -alias example.com
```

and i filled the several pieces of information required for the certificate.

the certificate successfully created. and i configured my server to access the keystore file but when restart my xmpp server it says

```
Unable to access certificate store. The keystore may be corrupt
```

what should i do for fixing the same issue ?

thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can :

1. Delete certs in AdminWEB interface.
2. Restart openfire
3. Delete /opt/openfire/resources/security/keystore file
4. Generate new cert from web interface.

References : http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ssl-guide.html

Hope this help...:)